# How to delete ParseObject if I have only objectID?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I did `findInBackground` query to get list of objects. After that I create my own objects from results I've gotten:

```
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(final List<ParseObject> hangOutList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < hangOutList.size(); i++) {
                    String objectID= hangOutList.get(i).getObjectId();
                    String city = hangOutList.get(i).getString("City");
                    String name = hangOutList.get(i).getString("Name");
                    String createdBy = 
                           hangOutList.get(i).getString("CreatedBy");
                    HangOut ho=new HangOut(objectID, name, city, createdBy);
                    hangOuts.add(ho);
                }
```

Now, when I click on one of them, I want to be able to delete it. In documentation, they say to do this: `myObject.deleteInBackground();`

However, I don't have `ParseObject` so I can't do that. Right now I was trying to do something like this:

```
private void deleteHangout() {
   ParseObject po=new ParseObject("HangOut");
    po.setObjectId(hangOut.getObjectID());
    po.deleteInBackground();
}
```

It doesn't work. Is there any way how to create Parse object by ID. Or any other idea?

**ERROR I get after executing `deleteHangout`:**

```
01-18 13:41:07.659    1716-1716/com.parse.starter E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Attempted to change an objectId to one that's  
        already known to the Offline Store.
        at com.parse.OfflineStore.updateObjectId(OfflineStore.java:598)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.setObjectIdInternal(ParseObject.java:1106)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.setObjectId(ParseObject.java:1094)
        at com.parse.starter.HangOuts.
           HangOutDetail.deleteHangout(HangOutDetail.java:61)
        at com.parse.starter.HangOuts.
           HangOutDetail.access$000(HangOutDetail.java:16)
        at com.parse.starter.HangOuts.
           HangOutDetail$1.onClick(HangOutDetail.java:54)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.
           ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**NOTE:** I want to avoid unnecessary calls to server.

Comment: You can just initialize a new parse object with that ID and apply the deletion to it

Comment: Isn't it that what I did? Last code section of my question? Or? Feel free to answer the question with the example. Thank you.

Comment: have you tried running a delete callback ?

Comment: Actually I think I did a mistake. I will fix it and let you know soon. My code seems to work, just my hangout is null, who knows why. Just a moment.

Comment: @AIL please check edit, that is the error I am getting after executing the method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What are you doing is that you are creating an object and then calling the method on another object that you just created , to do what you want you need to create a Parse object without [data](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#createWithoutData(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))   and then try to use the deleteEventually method so it deletes the object locally first and even if offline and once connected it will delete it from servers .

```
ParseObject po= ParseObject.createWithoutData("HangOut", hangOut.getObjectID());
po.deleteEventually();
```

Comment: It is not working in the case of ParseUser.ParseUser.createWithoutData("User","id"). What shall be done in case of ParseUser